# Script Path for CSS and Bundle is a bit off after WebPack Creates index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

For some reason, webpack is trying to append `client` to the href of the script tags for my CSS and bundle.  The problem with this is that it's wrong.  And I don't know how to tell it to trim that part off.

Before moving to webpack, here is how it looks in production when I was building it with Gulp:
[image]

notice above how everything was rooted from within the client folder.  You don't even see the client folder because I think expressJS said to start from that point so you only see the root of what's in client such as **lib**, **scripts**, etc.

here's what the dist directory looked like when I was using Gulp for that:
[image]

Here's how I'm serving my static assets.  My **ExpressJS** server sets the root folder for static asses as `dist/client`.  This has always been the case even when I was using Gulp:

```
  .use(
    express.static('dist/client', {
      maxage: oneYear,
    })
  )
```

**Forward to now:  It's using my new webpack.config now**

Here is a Screenshot of **dist** from IDE as it is now after using webpack:

[image]

But now the **index.html** is gened by webpack:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>My Title</title><meta charset="utf-8"><link href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/ink.min.css"><script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script><script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script><link href="../client/lib/assets/css/main.c09764908684c2f56919.css?c09764908684c2f56919" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="app"></div><script src="../client/scripts/app.c09764908684c2f56919.bundle.js?c09764908684c2f56919"></script></body></html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () => {
  return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './src/client/index.html',
    filename: './client/index.html',
    hash: true,
  });
};

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () => {
  return new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'client/lib/assets' },
      { from: 'src/server.js', to: './' },
      { from: 'src/api.js', to: './' },
      { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
      { from: 'ext', to: 'client/lib' },
      { from: 'feed.xml', to: 'client' },
      {
        from: 'src/shared',
        to: './shared',
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ['**/*supressed.json'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'client/scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['url-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: isProduction
    ? [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: isProduction
            ? 'client/lib/assets/css/main.[hash].css'
            : 'main.css',
        }),
        html(),
        copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
      ]
    : [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), html(), copyAllOtherDistFiles()],
};
```

Notice for my **bundle** the **src** generated includes `../client/` and same for my **href** for the **CSS** script.

The problem with this is that my app is served from the **root** of the `client` folder in dist.  You'd think that `../client/` or `./client/` or `client/` would work but it doesn't.  When I run the site I get this because it can't find the bundle:

[image]

As you can see below, everything it stemming from context of the **client** folder already in the browser:

[image]

(what's also odd about this after moving to webpack, is why do I see a **client** folder if I told ExpressJS to start from the client folder already?  When I was using the same exact code with Gulp, I did not see a client folder because I was already in it from the context of the browser)

So when I change the generated `index.html` *manually* in my dist folder, just to see if I can fix it, it all resolves just fine (notice I changed it to just `lib/` and `scripts/`):

```
</script><link href="lib/assets/css/main.c09764908684c2f56919.css?c09764908684c2f56919" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="app"></div><script src="scripts/app.c09764908684c2f56919.bundle.js?c09764908684c2f56919"></script></body></html>
```

The problem is I don't know how to get webpack to strip out that `..client/` part of the url when it gens the index.html.  **I've tried adding a publicPath property** with `'/'`, or `'./'` or `''` but no luck so far.

In other words this does not load: `http://localhost:8080/client/scripts/app.b4b3659d9f8b3681c26d.bundle.js`

but this does:

```
http://localhost:8080/scripts/app.b4b3659d9f8b3681c26d.bundle.js

http://localhost:8080/lib/assets/css/main.b4b3659d9f8b3681c26d.css
```

Comment: Can I see your webpack config file?

Comment: sorry, yes added it just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as long as you just write your output assets to same folder with the public folder set at your server, then it would work. Assuming the `client` will still be the public:

```js
.use(
  express.static('dist/client', {
    maxage: oneYear,
  })
)
```

I suggest to set entire output as `client` dir along side with its `publicPath` in webpack config for client:

```
output: {
  filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/client'),
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

with the setting above, we don't have to specify the folder the html template location:

```
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
  filename: 'index.html',
  hash: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand yet why this fixed it but here is what made it work.

**Definitely didn't need the publicPath:**

```
output: {
    filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
```

**Changed my static path to be:**

```
  .use(
    express.static('dist', {
      maxage: oneYear,
    })
  )
```

**move index.html out of the client folder and into the root of dist:**

```
return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    hash: true,
  });
```

Same with my bundle

output: {
filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
publicPath: '/',
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},

**Same with assets:**

```
patterns: [
      { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'lib/assets' },
```

I don't see what moving it to the **root** of `dist` makes any difference but for some reason rendering / requesting to process **index.html** from the **root** of `dist` instead of `dist/client` works`